# How to decode bytes to UTF-8 in java on an ubuntu VM?

Tags: java, utf-8, ubuntu-12.04

The following code snippet works on my linux desktop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { -61, -77 };
    String string = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    store(bytes, "/tmp/bytes");
    store(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "/tmp/string");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    baos.write(bytes);
    String other = baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    store(other.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "/tmp/other");

    checkResult(string);
    checkResult(other);
}

private static void store(byte[] bytes, String path) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(path))) {
        os.write(bytes);
    }
}

private static void checkResult(String string) throws Error {
    System.out.println(string);
    if (!string.equals("ó")) {
        throw new Error("invalid: " + string);
    }
}
```

It creates 3 files, each file contains an ó. It also prints an ó twice.
However, when I run this code on my server VM. Then the console shows `?` symbols instead of `ó`.

```
3.13.0-116-generic #163~precise1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-3~12.04-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Running the sample snippet like this fixes the console problem:

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar weird.jar`

The actual tomcat application calls javamail which sends out emails with the `?` symbol in them.
I can solve all the problems by setting the following property in JAVA_OPTS: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

However, I read somewhere that I should never touch this property, because it can break dependencies in strange ways.

I works for now. The only question left is whether there is a more acceptable way to do this (without risking dependencies breaking).

Answer (score 4):

It's almost never a good idea to call `String.getBytes()`.

Always pass in a `Charset`. 
 Usually, it's best to write

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

...
string.getBytes(UTF_8);
```

In your case, it's likely that `getBytes` is trying to use some other charset than UTF-8 and that's causing shenanigans.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. With that fix, all files are now written properly. However, the System.out.println statements are still displaying question marks. I can fix that by running the jar like so `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar weird.jar`. This also fixes the UTF characters for javamail (the real problem). However, I read somewhere that I should never ever do that, because it can break dependencies in stange ways. I will update the question.

Comment: That means the console you're using doesn't know how to use UTF-8.  Java can't do anything about that.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, you will absolutely have to do that, and if your dependencies are broken in strange ways they are doing bad things.  There's really no way around that.